# symfony : install and run behat on windows

Tags: java, symfony, testing, behat

I am trying to setup behat in my symfony2 application running locally on windows 8.

I have updated my composer, set up a behat.yml at the root and with phpStorm I am trying to launch behat. I get the following error :

> > bin/behat Cannot run program "D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\bin\behat" (in directory
> >     "D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev"): CreateProcess error=193,
> >     %1 is not a valid Win32 application

If I run from the command line outside phpStorm I get:

> 'behat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

If I run the file from the vendor directory right from the command line:

> '"@php_bin@"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Does someone have an idea of what I could do ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just had to run it with PHP and point directly to the vendor dir as the bin file is not considered a redirection